# How to use command prompt in eclipse to create Maven Project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, vaadin7

I am new to the Maven, Vaadin, Eclipse Kelper. I am working on project which include Maven, Vaadin.

I don't know how to create maven project using command prompt. I tried using Vaadin.com website, but not found the proper steps.

Answer (score 2):

you install maven plugin for eclipse. And then you will have facility to create maven projects in eclipse with GUI.

Comment: Sir, i am fine with the installation, the problem is how to use command prompt to create maven-vaadin project.
I need to use command prompt because every solution comes up with command prompt.

Comment: The m2e wizard allows creating project with the required maven archetypes; then you can execute maven builds with special Run configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial: https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Using+Vaadin+with+Maven

After that in eclipse you can import the project as existing maven project.